# Discord 1015 Cloudflare rate limit

Tags: api, https, discord

I was using the discord api to check for invites and I got 1015 cloudflare rate limited so does anyone know after how many requests you get rate limited?

I got rate limited after sending too many requests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Discord documentation states:](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#global-rate-limit)

> ### Invalid Request Limit aka CloudFlare bans
>
> IP addresses that make too many invalid HTTP requests are automatically and temporarily restricted from accessing the Discord API. Currently, this limit is **10,000 per 10 minutes.** An invalid request is one that results in 401, 403, or 429 statuses.

For bots:

> All bots can make up to 50 requests per second to our API. This is independent of any individual rate limit on a route. If your bot gets big enough, based on its functionality, it may be impossible to stay below 50 requests per second during normal operations.

It also says if your bot is getting Cloudflare banned, its likely not a global rate limit issue.